# How to save TensorFlow keras model as .js file

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

How to save TensorFlow-Keras model in `.js` (TensorFlow js) format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing `tensorflowjs` package try this code you may also need to install `ipython` package as

`pip install tensorflowjs`
`pip install -U ipython`

```
import tensorflowjs as tfjs
tfjs_target_dir = "./tfjs"
def train():
   model = keras.Sequential([
   keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(190, 190)),
   keras.layers.Dense(80, activation='relu'),
   keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')
  ])   # for example
   model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy']) # for example
   model.fit(train_data_images, train_data_labels, epochs=15) # for example
   tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, tfjs_target_dir)`
```